# Query where column contains range

Tags: google-sheets

I'm a bit new to the API query system, and I'm attempting to create a formula that works as follows:

```
=QUERY(A1:B20,"select A, sum(B) where A contains 'Apples' or A contains 'Oranges' group by A")
```

So, the table looks something like this:

```
Apples   3
Oranges 4
Melons  1
Apples   6
Apples   2
```

And I need it to return results like:

```
Apples 11
Oranges 4
Melons 1
```

The formula works for that purpose, but the list of different fruits that can go into Column A is extensive. Is there any way I can do something like:

```
=QUERY(A1:B20,"select A, sum(B) where A contains 'Sheet2!A2:A' group by A")
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify what I'm trying to do, heh.

Comment: Assuming that ColA contains only fruit names, you can simply query as `select A, sum(B) group by A`

Comment: Column A will have user entered text values based on a data validation dropdown I made. So the dropdown has the full list of fruits (and other items) which is nearly 100 items long, and column B will be the amount of each item entered.

Comment: Your ColA dropdown is the master list of fruits and the user would only select one fruit and a quantity per row ... right?

Comment: So my suggestion should work. If possible, share a test sheet.

Comment: Your suggestion did work. Apparently I was over-thinking it, lol. Thanks!

Comment: Cool ... glad that worked. Tick the answer so that the question can be  marked as Answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chat:

Change your query as `select A, sum(B) group by A`